# Renting an appartment in Poland using 'biuro'

Tags: rental, poland, warsaw

I'm going to say for at least a month in Warsaw.
If I rent a flat using 'biuro' - who pay commission: an owner or a guest? How big it usually is?

Comment: You mean using agency? It is (was?) one month rent, paid in half by onwer and the client.

Comment: Yes, it's about agency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you rent an appartment using real estate agency, there's de facto standard fee - 1 month rent, which is splitted 50/50 between the owner and the tenant.

Because the owner will be charged too, it's unlikely somebody will be interesting in such short-term rental through the agency, so you should look for direct offers (pl: bezpośredni).